# Enumerating\writing files in a specific directory hangs the command

Tags: filesystems, mount, ps

I'm communicating with a machine remotely through `ssh`. This machine runs a custom-built Linux and it has very limited set of commands.

At some point, a specific directory refuses files to be written to it. Running `ls`, hitting "tab" to auto-complete a file name or deleting files using a wild card, hangs the command.

After opening a new `ssh` session, hitting `ps | grep D` shows the following:

```
  PID  Uid        VSZ Stat Command
  628 root            DWN [jffs2_gcd_mtd4]
  930 root       2912 D   rm /mnt/flash/system/config
  995 root       2400 D   scp -t /mnt/flash/system/
 2083 root       3044 D   ls -AlSh /mnt/flash/system
 6994 root       2912 D   chmod +x /mnt/flash/system/config
13281 root       3052 S   grep D
22220 root       2400 D   scp -t /mnt/flash/system/
```

Running the `mount` command shows the following:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type ext2 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/mtdblock4 on /mnt/flash type jffs2 (rw)
```

Notice that the processes with the `D` state (Which indicates that the process is performing a disk I/O operation. This state shouldn't usually be observed, yet running `ps` multiple times shows the same state, so the process is actually stuck at a I/O operation) are either deleting, listing, editing or writing files to the mounted path `/mnt/flash`.

This mounted path file-system is `jffs2` (Notice that one of the processes shown is `jffs2_gcd_mtd4` with the state of `DWN`).

Keep in mind, I have no solid idea about Linux so please be as simple as possible.

- So what is the `DWN` state? Is it indicating that the processes cashed (i.e. down)?
- How can I resolve this problem? I can't edit files on this path and restarting the machine is an expensive option (i.e. logistics).

Comment: I can't even get mkfs.jffs2 to create a 10MB filesystem in a regular file under Ubuntu 13.04 without getting stuck in a endless, leaky loop. I'd consider jffs2 to be broken given that datum.

Comment: If you can run the command `dmesg` that might shed some light on the overall health of the machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ps status `DWN` is the combination of the flags:

```
D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
N    low-priority (nice to other users)
```

Being stuck in Disk-wait is the concerning which is pretty indicative of a driver bug. A driver attached to even a horribly broken drive should eventually timeout and return EIO to system calls accessing it.

If you are running a "custom-built" kernel as you say with a filesystem so rare that I'd not heard of it before your question where a driver can get stuck in an endless wait suggests you should consider your production machine broken.

Personally, I'd be wary of a driver that [appears to have been orphaned a decade ago](http://mhonarc.axis.se/jffs-dev/threads.html) especially since the [motivating reasons for creating the driver](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/jffs2.html#L_hdd_jffs2) have mostly been obviated by flash controller advances.

**added in response to comment**:

Unfortunately, a wedged driver will often seize the hardware channel and nothing short of a reboot can get it to release. You say that this device is operationally difficult to get to; I hope it's not on Mars. Before sending someone to restart it, make sure you remove the mount of the device (often in /etc/fstab, but it could be in — for example — /etc/rc.local) or else the system will likely hang again.

As @goldilocks noted in the comments, failed hardware is a distinct possibility, so if the flash is removable, I'd send the technician with replacement hardware. It is worth noting that flash memory has a limited number of write-cycles before failure and older flash had a lower number of write-cycles than modern flash.

Once the problem is cleared, you can build a new filesystem on the memory and mount it, provided your remote interface allows it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is there a way to `umount` the disk forcefully and remount it again using a different file-system ?

Comment: Not saying you are wrong, but you have downplayed the possibility of failing hardware. *"A driver attached to even a horribly broken drive should eventually timeout and return EIO to system calls accessing it."* How long is 'eventually' supposed to be? When this happens because of disk failure, it will tend to happen over and over and over again because a call failing does nothing to prevent the call from being repeated.  This *can* render a system unusable due to all the hanging I/O, and it is not because of bad drivers, it's bad hardware.

Comment: It could well be failing hardware, but my experiment with mkfs.jffs2 on a regular file on a known working ext3 filesystem combined with the orphan status of the driver inclines me to indifference as to whether it is hardware or software.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana see "added" above

Comment: jffs2 was designed for a particular type of hardware (MTD flash). This hardware isn't as common as it used to be, but as far as I know jffs2 is still appropriate for devices with cheaper kinds of flash memory. I remember `mkfs.jffs2` being kind of flaky, I wouldn't be surprised to see it crash if given atypical page/block sizes; and the driver plain won't work given the wrong kind of hardware.